# PHP: Save data in tree structure

Tags: php, arrays, excel, tree, treeview

I have an Excel looking lite this:

[image]

If I read it **(Edit: I use PHPExcel)**, I get for each row an Array looking like this:

```
$row = [Process, MainScrenario, Process1, Step1] // first row
$row = [null, null, null, Step2] // second row
```

Now I have multiple Excel-files each with different amount of columns.

I try to find a way, to parse these multiple **$row-Arrays** of an Excel to one big Array, with a tree-structure or something like this, to store the information.

Can someone help me here? How should I do this?

Comment: Use [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to parse the file and then iterate over the rows and store the last node in columns H, I and J to attach the next cell found to it.

Comment: @syck: I already use PHPExcel and iterate over the rows. The Excel files have different amount of columns.

Comment: As I said, go top->down and inside left->right. Attach _MainScenario_ to _Process_, _Process1_ to _MainScenario_ and _Step1_ to _Process1_. Keep for each column the last branch you have seen before and attach all fields that are more right (have a higher columns index) to that. When you see _SecScenario_, it has to be attached to _Process_ in _First Name_ column, because thats what you have kept as last node for column _H_.

Comment: @syck: I understood your logic, thanks. But how do I attach the things together. I am a bit lost here.

Comment: Use objects which contain your content (ie. the field content) and an array of references to the lower-level nodes. Then you can traverse the tree from the top all the way through. Should fit nicely into a class structure with the functions you need to build and traverse the tree. (These will have to cover attach node, get node content and get subnodes.)

Comment: @syck Is it possible to share an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to make up the comments from above into a coding example. Modify this to fulfill your needs:

```
<?php

// prepare data
$data = array(
  ['Process', 'MainScenario', 'Process1', 'Step1'],
  [null, null, null, 'Step2'],
  [null, null, null, 'Step3'],
  [null, null, null, 'Step3'],
  [null, null, 'Process2', 'Step1'],
  [null, null, null, 'Step2'],
  [null, 'SecScenario', 'Process1', 'Step1'],
  [null, null, null, 'Step2'],
  [null, null, 'Process2', 'Step1'],
  [null, null, null, 'Step2'],
  [null, null, null, 'Step3'],
);

// define class which holds the nodes
class node {
  private $text = '';                                      // the text (name) of the node
  private $children = array();                             // list of the children of the node

  function __construct($text) {                            // constructor. sets the text
    $this->text = $text;
  }

  function addChild(&$ref) {                               // add a child
    $this->children[] = $ref;                              // store reference to child in $this->children array property
  }

  function getText() {                                     // get text of the node
    return $this->text;                                    // retrieve textdomain
  }

  function getChildren() {                                 // get children of the node
    return $this->children;                                // fetch & deliver array
  }

  function __toString() {                                  // magic function for conversion to string
    return $this->getText();                               // is an alias for $this->getText
  }
}

// parse the data into a tree
function buildTree($data) {
  $start = array();                                         // list of all root nodes
  $last = array();                                          // list of last-seen nodes on every depth

  foreach ($data as $row) {                                 // iterate over all rows
    $depth = 0;                                             // reset depth (start form left)
    foreach ($row as $cell) {                               // iterate over all cells in the row
      if (!is_null($cell) && $cell!='') {                   // empty cell? if so, ignore
        if ($depth==0) {                                    // top layer?
          $obj = new node($cell.' (R)');                    // this is a root node
          $start[] = $obj;                                  // add to list of root nodes
          $last[0] = $obj;                                  // set as root node
        }
        else {
          $parent = null;                                   // we want to find a parent object
          for ($dd = $depth-1; $dd>=0; $dd--) {             // traverse up to root
            if (isset($last[$dd])) {                        // $last for this level set?
              $parent = $last[$dd];                         // accept it as parent
              break;                                        // do not search further
            }
          }

          if (!is_null($parent)) {                          // parent found?
            $obj = new node($cell.' ('.$depth.')');         // create new node for this entry
            $parent->addChild($obj);                        // attach it to the parent
            $last[$depth] = $obj;                           // set object as $last for this level
          }
        }
      }
      $depth++;                                             // increase depth (advance right)
    }
  }

  return $start;                                            // return list of root nodes
}

// show the tree descending from a single node given
function showTree($node, $depth = 0) {                     // recursively output nodes
  echo str_repeat('> ', $depth).$node->getText().PHP_EOL;  // this node
  foreach ($node->getChildren() as $subnode) {             // iterate over child nodes
    showTree($subnode, $depth+1);                          // recursive call for children
  }
}

// execute
$rootNodes = buildTree($data);                             // build the tree
foreach($rootNodes as $node) {                             // iterate over root nodes
  showTree($node);                                         // show tree for each of them
}

?>
```

produces:

```
Process (R)
> MainScenario (1)
> > Process1 (2)
> > > Step1 (3)
> > > Step2 (3)
> > > Step3 (3)
> > > Step3 (3)
> > Process2 (2)
> > > Step1 (3)
> > > Step2 (3)
> SecScenario (1)
> > Process1 (2)
> > > Step1 (3)
> > > Step2 (3)
> > Process2 (2)
> > > Step1 (3)
> > > Step2 (3)
> > > Step3 (3)
```

The numbers in the parentheses are the actual `$depth` level the node is added at. (R) denotes a root node.

See demo **[here](https://eval.in/554082)**.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you very much. Just one more question, while you know your code best: What do I need to change, if I have an Excel where the fields aren't "null" like in my example but have the same name as the row above?

Comment: Just compare them with the actual content of `$last` for the given `$depth` (or its string representation).

Comment: Can you give me a more detailed hint? I need to add something where you check if `!is_null($cell)` like `|| $cell.' ('.$depth.')' == $last[$depth]->getText()`. Am I right?

Comment: `$last` always contains the last object seen for the particular column (which is denoted by depth). So your complarison would be `if (!is_null($cell) && $cell!='' && $cell!=$last[$depth]->getText()) {`, if you remove the `.' ('.$depth.')'` part on the content creation (which was mainly for debugging and clarification purposes and is not required.)

Comment: Another possibility would be to use different class attribute for holding the name and the content of the node. This was intended to be a proof of concept, not as working production code. Feel free to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: If I do this it fails in the first iteration because there is no element in `$last`, so I can't call `->getText()`. Is there any way to check this in the if itself?

Comment: yeah I know isset() but I can't just check if, because if `$last` is empty this is no reason to return false to this if-clause. I would need something like another if-clause in this if-clause, saying if isset($last) then check if the text of the last element in this depth is like the cellname. And only if so break.

Comment: `$last` is empty, so there has been no element before for this columns, so the condition must evaluate to true. Additionally, you would not check for `$last` but rather for `$last[$depth]`. -- Just take some time to think it through and understand which task every statement fulfills.

Comment: Oh you are right. So finally: Thank you very very much for your time and your input. It really helped me. Thanks!